# returning two values from one function in c++

Tags: c++, function, return-value

Can I return two values from function one intiger and boolean? I tried to do this in this way but its doesnt work.

```
int fun(int &x, int &c, bool &m){
        if(x*c >20){
           return x*c;
          m= true;
            }else{
                return x+c;
                m= false;
                }


fun(x, c, m);
    if(m) cout<<"returned true";
    else cout<<"returned false";

        }
```

Comment: You can only return one object from a function, but the object can be of an arbitrarily complex type.

Comment: You can use a `std::tuple`.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a struct which contains two values as its members. You can then return that struct, and access the individual members.

Thankfully, `C++` does this for you by the `pair` class. To return an `int` and a `bool`, you can use `pair<int,bool>`.

Comment: I once heard a Scott M. talk where he strongly suggested not to use a `pair` whenever you know what it actually is and I completely agree. A `struct { int day;int month }` is always preferable to a `pair<int,int>` or a `struct { int counter;bool expired }` is better than a `pair<int,bool>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can return a `struct` that contains some values.

```
struct data {
    int a; bool b;
};


struct data func(int val) {
    struct data ret;
    ret.a=val;
    if (val > 0) ret.b=true;
    else ret.b=false;
    return ret;
}


int main() {
    struct data result = func(3);
    // use this data here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need for `struct data` aside from the declaration. C++ ain't C, you know. Also close the `struct` declaration with `;`.